# Can I play among us on ubuntu?

Tags: games

I see option of buying the game but I am not too sure if this works on ubuntu. Want to be sure before spending money

Comment: A new game, I would doubt it.  Would check if it is available on Stream for Linux.

Comment: Found this from reddit, do not know how easy or good it will be.  https://segmentnext.com/2018/12/06/steam-proton-guide/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, at least on my machine.

- Install Steam and buy the game.
- Force the use of Proton.
- Configure the Launch Options (from [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/play-among-us-linux/), step 4):
  `PROTON_NO_ESYNC=1 PROTON_USE_WINED3D=1 %command%`
- Install the game.
- Start the game -- may download additional dependencies (e.g. Proton).

[image: Screenshot from Steam]

Comment: Not on my machine. It seems you're more likely to run into trouble if your GPU does not support Vulkan. See [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/issues/4190) for some common issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may alternatively look into installing Anbox, an android emulator for Linux, as the game is free and very lightweight on Android.

```
sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox
```

See [here](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-anbox-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa/) for more elaborate instructions on Ubuntu 20.04.

Anbox does require your CPU to support [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions), which mine does not, so I cannot report on whether this is actually possible.

Comment: I went this path yesterday, installed Anbox, [configured my keyboard layout](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/253#issuecomment-449777527), [added ARM support & the Play Store](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/anbox-how-to-install-google-play-store.html) and installed Among Us from it, but all I got was a black screen. I also tried [this workaround](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1593#issuecomment-691255286) without success. I uninstalled everything afterwards. It seems [some guy got it working on Genymotion](https://jetong.me/blog/technical/2020/09/21/amongus/) but with lag.